# Spring Boot 2 / GraphQL Extended Scalars not working: Exception "Cannot construct instance" "cannot deserialize"

Tags: spring-boot, graphql

I've got a working setup for a GraphQL API (Spring Boot 2, GraphQL Spring Boot Starter, GraphiQL).

Then I tried to introduce a custom scalar provided by the library *graphql-java-extended-scalars* (in this case the *DateScalar* for a member with the type *java.time.LocalDate*):

I declared the custom scalar and the type in the schema,

```
scalar Date
...
  somedate: Date
...
```

I provided `GraphQLScalarType` as a Spring Bean (otherwise the server wouldn't start up):

```java
@Bean
public GraphQLScalarType date() {
   return ExtendedScalars.Date;
}
```

I executed a mutation query with a *Date*.

```js
mutation {
  createSomething(
    something:{
      ...
      somedate: "2018-07-20",
      ...
    }
  )
}
```

But unfortunately I get this exception,

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `java.time.LocalDate` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

After some hours of research, I have no idea what could be wrong. It seems that the Scalar was not picked up despite provided in the configuration.

The `GraphQLInputType` looks like this,

```java
@Data
public class Something implements GraphQLInputType {

    ...
    private LocalDate somedate;
    ...

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Something";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think after providing SchemaParserOptions with a adjusted configuration of mapper it works:

```
@Bean
public SchemaParserOptions schemaParserOptions(){
   return SchemaParserOptions.newOptions().objectMapperConfigurer((mapper, context) -> {
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    }).build();
}
```

GraphQL uses its own objectmapper, therefore you have to register the JavaTimeModule on it.

Comment: Works - Great - Thank you! Now I found more information about this for example here: https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-spring-boot/issues/32

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the class where you want to deserialize the object it doesn't have a public default constructor.

Comment: Thank you. I checked this, but the class has a public no args constructor (via Lombok annotation @Data).(The exception message says: Cannot construct instance of `java.time.LocalDate`

Comment: Can you provide your class as well?

Comment: I added an example resembling the class.

Comment: Do you have a public setter? Jackson should have access to your class attributes either by public args constructor or by public no args constructor and public setters.

Comment: The public no args constructor and the setters/getters are generated by lombok @Data. But I even tried without lombok which shouldn't make a difference anyway. So yes, all those methods are there.